# Using scp to copy a file to Amazon EC2 (Ubuntu) instance?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I cd to the file in my local computer, which contains the filkekey.pem. Then I use the code

```
scp -i file_key.pem part.txt ubuntu@ec2-54-149-103-26.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:
```

It returns:

```
Warning: Identity file_key.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

How could I deal with this situation?

---

#### Solved

I should log out the EC2, then doing the copy work.

Comment: you say `which contains the filekey.pem` (no underscore), then use `file_key.pem` (with underscore) in your command. which is it?

Comment: I made a silly mistake. I should log out EC2. then doing the copy work. Thank you for your help! @MarcB

Answer (score 0):

The file file_key.pem is located in the directory where your are running the command ?

Use correctly permissions over the file is important  too, thats could be done with the next line

```
sudo chmod 600 file_key.pem
```